# Rails 6 polymorphic model giving validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm upgrading a Rail 5.2 application to Rails 6 and am running into an error with one of my polymorphic models. It can belong_to several other models but itself only requires a body.

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :profession
  belongs_to :topic

  has_many :notes, as: :notable, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :body, presence: true, allow_blank: false
end
```

When I create or edit a note, even if it has a body and user and notable set correctly, the validation fails because it says profession and topic can't be blank.

> => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00005622cd43ed10 @base=#<Note id: 768, notable_type: "Topic", notable_id: 4735, user_id: 8050, body: "foo", created_at: "2020-07-22 21:55:41", updated_at: "2020-07-22 21:55:41", communal: true, is_card: false, title: "test">, @messages={:topic=>["must exist"], :profession=>["must exist"]}, @details={:topic=>[{:error=>:blank}], :profession=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>

If I comment out the `belongs_to` in the above model, it validates fine.

I searched the docs to see if that behavior could be explained anywhere but nothing in the validations or upgrade guide seems to deal with gotchas around polymorphic associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now need to add `optional: true` to a belongs_to or rails adds a validation by default.  See below:

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :profession, optional: true
  belongs_to :topic, optional: true

  has_many :notes, as: :notable, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :body, presence: true, allow_blank: false
end
```

Documentation for this is here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#new-framework-defaults